# Metro Application How to Read XML API?

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Ok so I am trying to learn how to work with XAML and how to build new windows metro applications using Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview.

I have a problem though I don't know how to read XML files the same way I use to using C#. For example here is how I did it in the past.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string UrlString = "http://v1.sidebuy.com/api/get/73d296a50d3b824ca08a8b27168f3b85/?city=nashville&format=xml";
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(UrlString);
            XmlNodeType type;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                type = reader.NodeType;

                if ((type == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "highlights"))
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                        if (reader.Value != "" && reader.Value != null)
                        {
                            listBox1.Items.Add(reader.Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

But this won't work in my metro application. I need to know how to do this for metro. Apparently XmlTextReader is no longer valid. Any code or suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: `XmlTextReader` has been deprecated for ages. Have you tried using its suggested replacement, `XmlReader.Create`, instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206266.aspx). This should also make your code a lot simpler.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string UrlString = "http://v1.sidebuy.com/api/get/73d296a50d3b824ca08a8b27168f3b85/?city=nashville&format=xml";
            var xmlDocument = await XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(UrlString);

            //read from xmlDocument for your values.
         }
```

EDIT: Fixed code based on comment.

Comment: Uri UrlString = new Uri("http://v1.sidebuy.com/api/get/73d296a50d3b824ca08a8b27168f3b85/?city=nashville&format=xml");
            var xmlDocument = XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(UrlString);

Comment: when I converted it to a Uri type it seems to not throw an error, but now i am confused how to read it.

Comment: Your url has an extra " at the end and it seems to be returning JSON in that case if your remove that it should work. The returned object is of type XmlDocument. Here is a link (http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=312) that will help you read the file.

Comment: @Christian I fixed the code, you are right it is an async operation.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the async/await keyworks to the method

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

var xmlDocument = await XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(UrlString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also XmlSerializer class which allows you to declare the object types used in your xml and maps directly to them. The Deserialize and Serialize methods work with any stream and greatly simplify using xml data.

```
var xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(yourcollectionclass), new []{typeof(yourchildclass1),typeof(yourchildclass2)});
var xml = (yourcollectionclass) xml.deserialize(stream)
```