# Read XML using XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(UrlString)?

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, xmldocument

I am trying to read a bit of XML and want to read it using the code below as this is for a metro windows 8 application. I could use some help though on how to parse out each node/element etc. Thanks!

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri UrlString = new Uri("http://v1.sidebuy.com/api/get/73d296a50d3b824ca08a8b27168f3b85/?city=nashville&format=xml");
    var xmlDocument = XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(UrlString);

    text1.Text = xmlDocument.ToString();
}
```

Comment: We would be glad to help you, but we need to know what exactly is you problem to do that. What do you want to do? What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: well to be honest. I just want to create a simple program to show the xml feed. But I am utterly new to xaml. I thought this would be easy to start with. I was told i should use the above to parse the XML I was wanting to use. this post got derived from my original question at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477158/metro-application-how-to-read-xml-api/9485522#comment12253186_9485522

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell whether you're confused by the XML part or the async part. You don't do the parsing yourself at all - `XmlDocument` does that (although I'd recommend using LINQ to XML if you can). However, your variable name and `ToString` call suggest you haven't understood that `LoadFromUriAsync` returns an [`IAsyncOperation<XmlDocument>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206598.aspx), not an `XmlDocument`.

Effectively, it represents the promise that an `XmlDocument` will be available at some point in the future. That's where C# 5's async methods come into play... if you change `Button_Click` into an async method, you can write:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("...");
    XmlDocument xmlDocument = await XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(UrlString);
    text1.Text = xmlDocument.ToString();
}
```

Now your method will actually *return* to the caller (the UI event loop) when it hits the await expression, assuming that the document hasn't become instantly available... but then when the document has been fetched, the rest of your method will execute (back on the UI thread) and you'll have the document which you can use as if you'd fetched it synchronously.

Comment: Oh thanks for the information! Now I am a tad bit more lost...but what you said at least puts me on a better track.

Comment: @allencoded: async is a big topic... I would strongly suggest diving into blogs and MSDN :)

Comment: thanks, by the way i was told the code above was the best way to parse XML for the new metro apps which are built around xaml. XAML is new to me. I really wanted to create a simple program to list top sells in area to learn more of it. but it has been a headache so far.

Comment: @allencoded: It sounds like you've got a lot to take in. I would take one step at a time rather than trying to get it all in one go. I see this isn't the `System.Xml.XmlDocument` class though... I haven't looked into the Metro APIs yet, to be honest.

Comment: yeah confusing so far...it all derived from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477158/metro-application-how-to-read-xml-api/9485522#comment12253186_9485522

Comment: @allencoded: I suggest you find a really good Metro tutorial then, rather than trying to pick it up via SO. SO is *great* for specific questions, but doesn't present a good step-by-step way of learning. Good luck! (And I hope this helps eventually!)