# XmlDocument cannot find the specfied file

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I just upgraded my Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight app to a Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime app.
Unfortunately, I have to downgrade this app to a 8.1 SL project, because Windows Runtime lacks Google Admob support.

That aside, in my 8.1 RT project I use the following code to fetch a XML feed:

```
private async void GetData()
{
    XmlDocument regenthetinXML = await XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(new Uri("http://regenthet.in/data/regenthetin.xml", UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

The [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/apps/windows.data.xml.dom.xmldocument.loadfromuriasync.aspx) class is supported at both platforms, but when I use exactly the same code in my Windows Phone 8.1 SL project I get exceptions like this one:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
```

Any suggestions? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look here at this previous `SO` posting looks to be similar in nature.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650232/read-xml-using-xmldocument-loadfromuriasyncurlstring

Answer (score 0):

Use a `WebClient` to retrieve the string first.

```
string xmlStr;
string m_strFilePath = "http://regenthet.in/data/regenthetin.xml";
using(var wc = new WebClient())
{
    xmlStr = wc.DownloadString(m_strFilePath);
}
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);
```

On mobile, if you don't have `DownloadString`, use `DownloadStringAsync` with an additional event handler to `DownloadStringCompleted`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know you can use the WebClient class to retrieve datafiles etc, but why isn't it possible to fetch external datafiles on the Silverlight platform on the way as described above. It is the same XmlDocument class, how can I notice the difference of functionality between the two platforms?

Comment: Does the code work for you? Yes, regarding the difference in functionality between two platforms, there are some methods in desktop which are not there on phone (like cryptography). Maybe, by forcing `Async` on us, we are driven to responsive UI models