# Deserialization of XML into Multiple Objects of the Same Type (For Windows 8 App)

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

So I'm trying to deserialize the following XML Document into multiple objects of my custom type (ItemModel). Since I'm developing for the Windows 8 platform, I've been hitting a lot of blocks due to library incompatibilities. What I'm trying to do is deserialize each ItemModel into an object than add them to a List of some sort. From what I have, the code runs but the list is not populating.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Items>
  <ItemModel>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <Name>Apple</Name>
    <Category>Compost</Category>
    <ImageWidth>67</ImageWidth>
    <ImageHeight>100</ImageHeight>
    <Description>An Apple is a compost item that....</Description>
    <ImagePath>Graphics\\apple.png</ImagePath>
  </ItemModel>
  <ItemModel>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <Name>Water Bottle</Name>
    <Category>Mixed Containers</Category>
    <ImageWidth>67</ImageWidth>
    <ImageHeight>100</ImageHeight>
    <Description>A Water bottle is a mixed container item that...</Description>
    <ImagePath>Graphics\\Bottle.png</ImagePath>
  </ItemModel>
</Items>
```

Note: I'm also experiencing some trouble using the XmlReader. It's the reader us equal to null even after I use XmlReader.Create().

Thank you.

Comment: How do you get your data? Is is a string, a file, stream?

Comment: From a File. I couldn't use FileStream, which was used by most examples, because its not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are reading from a .xml file and displaying in Web browser and your code behind is C#, you can do something like this :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {                 
      ReadXmlFile(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFiles/Items.xml"));
 }

 private void ReadXmlFile(string fileName)
 {
    string parentElementName = "";
    string childElementName = "";
    string childElementValue = "";
    bool element = false;
    lblMsg.Text = "";

    XmlTextReader xReader = new XmlTextReader(fileName);
    while (xReader.Read())
    {
        if (xReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            if (element)
            {
                parentElementName = parentElementName + childElementName + "<br>";
            }
            element = true;
            childElementName = xReader.Name;
        }
        else if (xReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text | xReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.CDATA)
        {
            element = false;
            childElementValue = xReader.Value;
            lblMsg.Text = lblMsg.Text + "<b>" + parentElementName + "<br>" + childElementName + "</b><br>" + childElementValue;

            parentElementName = "";
            childElementName = "";
        }
    }
    xReader.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. I don't think XmlTextReader is supported by .net for windows store apps (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml(v=vs.110).aspx). Would you happen to know of alternatives?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477158/metro-application-how-to-read-xml-api   and here you have your answer in this external link http://dandar3.blogspot.in/2011/11/parsing-large-xmls-with-xmlreader-and.html

Comment: Windows Phone 8 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/libr...v=vs.105).aspx

Windows 8 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/libr.../br230232.aspx